# Find the time of setting up and going online of a Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I want to find the time of setting up and going online of a Wordpress site. Is there any way to do it From the site URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can look on the time of file creation/modification.

Comment: How can I look that from front end (Page source or else)?

Comment: With this [plugin](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/cysteme-finder/screenshots/) for example.

Comment: With this type of plugins those info can be viewed only after login as admin in wp-admin. My query was can I find such info from user end, such I have  only the website address like: www.example.com. How can I get such info of this site while I am simply a visitor?

Comment: Sorry. My bad, I think about back and.  
From front-end you can see on some js or css files.